# PHP - How do I set the value of a multidimensional array property from 'outside' the class?

Tags: php, properties, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to wrap my head around something that I can't seem to figure out a solution for. In class A I have a property which is a multidimensional array. In  class B which is instantiated within class A, I'd like to set an index value for the property from class A. I run into a wall where I have no idea how to iterate through the property to set the value for the index I'd need to. Here's a test example of what I mean:

```
<?php

class SomeClass
{
    protected $class;
    protected $book;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->book["genre"]["title"] = "The Haunting";
    }


    public function SomeTest()
    {
        $this->class = new AnotherClass();
        $this->class->AnotherTest();
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    protected function setBook()
    {
        $indexes = func_get_args();
        $value   = array_pop($indexes);

        /**
         * So now I have the indexes which lead to the array
         * depth I'd like to set a value to, but where do I
         * go from here?
         *
         */
    }

    public function AnotherTest()
    {
        $this->setBook("something", "else", "1984");
    }
}



$someclass = new SomeClass();
$someclass->SomeTest();
```

?>

I'm so lost on how to do what I'm thinking of.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to access `SomeClass` from within `AnotherClass`, kind of like a "parent" property? Because that's impossible, you'd have to pass `AnotherClass` a reference to the parent. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to access the multidimensional property in SomeClass from within AnotherClass, and in whichcase I could do something like $this->class = new AnotherClass($this); in order to pass the reference, and set the reference in the constructor for AnotherClass. But, I'm still a total fog on how to set the values of the multidimensional array. :(

Comment: aren't you doing almost that already? From within `AnotherClass`, it will be `$this->class->book["genre"]["title"] = "The Haunting";`

Comment: I can't because it's protected. In the real application the multidimensional array would be storing GET and POST data which I'm worried about making accessible by making the property public. Am I right to be worried in that regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initiate class Another with a parameter, pass initiator class!

```
class SomeClass{
    public function SomeTest()    {
        $this->class = new AnotherClass($this);
        $this->class->AnotherTest();
    }
}
```

I use creator for these situations!

```
class AnotherClass{
    function __contruct($creator){
        $this->creator=$creator
    }

    function AnotherTest(){
        $this->creator->setBook("something", "else", "1984");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the need to pass the reference ( which I accidentally left out of my example ). Though, unfortunately that is not the problem I'm trying to resolve. I'm still lost on how to set values for the multidimensional property I mentioned from within AnotherTest.

Comment: Then question is how to iterate an array?

Comment: It's more of how to set the value or a protected property which is a multidimensional array in class A, from class B which is instantiated within class A. Perhaps there's something fundamentally wrong with the approach I'm trying....

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation why you are not using inheritance? Your property is protected and I think it should not be accessible outside the class.

Hay you tried with inheritance?.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or refer me to an example?

Comment: class AnotherClass extends SomeClass
{//write you method here to set value in protected property
} This link may be helpful http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php